# Paste value from ListBox to default columns (row under selected field)

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, copy-paste, offset

I tried to paste value from ListBox: alwyas one row below selection, into column C, D, E, F.

my code:

```
Dim addme as Range
Set addme = Application.Selection

    For x = 0 To Me.lbsourceList.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lbsourceList.Selected(x) Then        

            'addme.Offset(1, ) = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 1)'
            'addme.Offset(1, ) = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 2)'
            'addme.Offset(1, ) = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 3)'
            'addme.Offset(1, ) = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 4)'

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)      
        End If
    Next x
```

Offset (1,0) will go under one row below, but I don't know how to set up column C, D, E, F as defualt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, to get the `Offset` working of `Selection`, but at Column C.

```
Dim addme As Range
Set addme = Selection

' set the range to selection's row, but in Column C
Set addme = Cells(Selection.Row, "C")

' now offset 1 row below
addme.Offset(1) = "test offset"
```

**Edit 1**: updated code to fit PO's new data:

```
Range(Cells(addme.Row, "C"), Cells(addme.Row, "C")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 1)
Range(Cells(addme.Row, "D"), Cells(addme.Row, "D")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 2)
Range(Cells(addme.Row, "E"), Cells(addme.Row, "E")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 3)
Range(Cells(addme.Row, "F"), Cells(addme.Row, "F")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 4)
```

Comment: what I I need to other value paste to column D, next to column E etc...I need to setup a few addme?

Comment: this code answers your post, if you want to more information then update your post